# Index pdf files to AWS Elasticsearch service using Elasticsearch File System Crawler

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, fscrawler

I can index pdf files to a local Elasticsearch using [Elasticsearch File System Crawler](https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler#user-guide). The default, fscrawler setting has port, host and scheme parameters as shown below.

```
{
"name" : "job_name2",
"fs" : {
"url" : "/tmp/es",
"update_rate" : "15m",
"excludes" : [ "~*" ],
"json_support" : false,
"filename_as_id" : false,
"add_filesize" : true,
"remove_deleted" : true,
"add_as_inner_object" : false,
"store_source" : false,
"index_content" : true,
"attributes_support" : false,
"raw_metadata" : true,
"xml_support" : false,
"index_folders" : true,
"lang_detect" : false,
"continue_on_error" : false,
"pdf_ocr" : true,
"ocr" : {
  "language" : "eng"
}
},
 "elasticsearch" : {
"nodes" : [ {
  "host" : "127.0.0.1",
  "port" : 9200,
  "scheme" : "HTTP"
} ],
"bulk_size" : 100,
"flush_interval" : "5s"
},
"rest" : {
"scheme" : "HTTP",
"host" : "127.0.0.1",
"port" : 8080,
"endpoint" : "fscrawler"
}
}
```

However, I have difficulty using it to index to AWS elasticsearch service because to index to AWS elasticsearch, I have to provide the AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY, region, and service as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-indexing-programmatic.html).Any help on how to index pdf files to AWS elasticsearch service is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a postman query on AWS elasicsearch . If yes what response did you get?

Answer (score 0):

FSCrawler does not support yet providing `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` or `AWS_SECRET_KEY`.
May be worth opening an issue in FSCrawler?

That said, https://cloud.elastic.co is supported but using "login/password". [See documentation for more details](https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/fs/elasticsearch.html#node-settings).